# Reachability code not working accurately in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, reachability

In my application i want to check server accessibility before going to the next screen when a button is tapped.

I have used tony million reachability and AFNetworking reachability, they are all working fine. **But the issue is when i turned off my wifi, it is taking 10 secs time to reflect the same in iPad, meantime if i check the server connectivity it is showing that server is reachable (i am using iPadAir and it is not connected to Mobile Data). After iPad is detecting that wifi is switched off only it is giving not reachable**. i even tried with apple simple ping example, still i am getting the same issue.

Please advice

Comment: if you are setting up notifications to be noticed when there is a change in reachability, make sure you are making all of the setup on the main thread. For instance, ApplicationFinished, the place where such a setup is most appropriate, is not on the main thread. The lib you found working, solves your problem probably because it invokes the main thread to set things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution

[Please go through this website](http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-ping-a-server-in-objective-c-iphone/)

SimplePingHelper is written on top of SimplePing and is very easy to use

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run reachability function viewdidload and save value. Use this value buttonPress event and in buttonPress event Run reachability function on background again.